# JavaScript property accessors wrapped in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I'm failing to find documentation as to how/why the following works:

```
const data = {one: 1, two: 2}
const key = ['one']

data[key[0]] // 1
data[key] // 1
data[[key]] // 1  
data[[[key]]] // 1
data[[[[key]]]] // 1
data[['one', 'two']] // undefined
```

What allows any number of square brackets to surround the key and still successfully find the key in the object? Is there specific behavior when `array.length === 1`? And if so, where can I find documentation or clarity on that?

Comment: It's documented in [`Array#toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

Comment: Just FYI, this behavior is not specific to ES 6. It would work the same if you replaced `const` with `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `object[key]` bracket notation to access properties, the `key` is converted to a string.* The string representation of an array is the string representations of its elements joined with `,`. For a one-element array, that's the same as the string representation of its only element.

```
const foo = {'a,b': 2};
console.log(foo[['a', 'b']]); // 2;
```

* Or a symbol.

Comment: `['a'].toString() => 'a'`, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you access a property using square brackets, the key is always converted to string. And if you convert an array to string, the result is the same as calling the `join()` method on the array. Therefore, converting to string an array, which contains only one element, which is a string results in that element itself. However, when array contains two string elements (like `['one', 'two']`), converting it to string results in `'one,two'`, and the `data` variable doesn't contain that key.